# Hibernate 6 column defined as "timestamp with time zone" does not show UTC offset in ZonedDateTime

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, primefaces, jsf-2.2

After upgrading Hibernate from 5.2 to 6.2.0.CR4, on PostgreSQL v13, column data type="timestamp with time zone", ex value: "2023-04-13 04:42:16.992755-04", defined as java.time.ZonedDateTime, in UTC offset shows letter 'Z' instead of 'UTC'.

[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK23J.png)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@Column(name="updated_at")
private ZonedDateTime updatedAt;
```

[PostgreSQL column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXZoF.png)

```
Apr. 13, 2023 04:46p.m. Z
Apr. 13, 2023 04:42p.m. Z
Apr. 12, 2023 04:13p.m. Z
Apr. 12, 2023 04:13p.m. Z
```

<hibernate.core.version>6.2.0.CR4</hibernate.core.version>

**application.properties (springboot v3.x)**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE_UTC
```

- on Hibernate 5.2 it was 'UTC' instead of 'Z' for timezone.

appreciate the help,
--vs

Comment: Are you implying that 'UTC' is correctly printed when you use `System.out.println(...)` instead of a whole JSF based web interface? If not then this is not a JSF/OmniFaces problem and you should remove this noise from the question to make it better focused for the Hibernate experts.

Comment: Nice point, thanks! 
Indeed you right, `System.out.println(...)` on ZonedDateTime column from PostgreSQL returns `Apr. 13, 2023 04:46p.m. Z` if formatted with `MMM dd, yyyy hh:mma z`. 
Will update the question now.

Answer (score 0):

The whole issue is boiling down to update usage
of java.util.Date(JDK8) to java.time.ZonedDateTime(JDK17)
while showing the output of ZonedDateTime with TimeZone in JSF view(using PrimeFaces)
under SpringFramework(w/ Spring Boot, and JoinFaces).

Possible solution found so far (if anyone found any better, please post it too):

```
<p:dataTable ...
<p:column>
    <h:panelGroup id="auditUpdatedAt">
        <h:outputText value="#{manageDummyView.myConvert(dummy.updatedAt)}">
            <f:convertDateTime type="zonedDateTime" pattern="MMM dd, yyyy hh:mma z"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </h:panelGroup
</p:column>
...
</p:dataTable>
```

`dummy.updatedAt` - ZonedDateTime object

Than later on in the Java back end code we add our conversion method

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ViewScoped
public class ManageDummyView implements Serializable {

    public ZonedDateTime myConvert(ZonedDateTime zdt)
    {
        if (zdt == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        ZonedDateTime zdtZoned = zdt.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return zdtZoned;
    }
```

And thus I get correct zone value in GUI: "Jan. 19, 2024 09:00p.m. EST"

Thanks to @BalusC!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**